# firebase orderByChild returns weird order for only one child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase schema containing the table 'Catalog' with a few values

**Catalog Table**

[image]

I did an orderByChild() using avgDrinkPrice as the order and the output was wrong.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
myRef.orderByChild("avgDrinkPrice").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            catalogList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Catalog catalog = postSnapshot.getValue(Catalog.class);
                catalogList.add(catalog);
                Log.d(TAG,"Drink price " + catalog.getAvgDrinkPrice());
                catalogSize++;
            }
            //LOOP ENDS.
```

I have tried sorting using other numerical values such as the latitude field, longitude and rating and their orders are correct. **Only when sorting by avgDrinkPrice would the order be wrong.** I don't understand why. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to your screenshot, the `avgDrinkPrice` property is a `string`, so the results *are* sorted correctly. It's just that they are sorted lexographically - not numerically.

There is more information on how Firebase sorts data, when ordering by child, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#orderbychild):

> When using `orderByChild()`, data that contains the specified child key will be ordered as follows:
>
> 1. Children with a `null` value for the specified child key come first.
> 2. Children with a value of `false` for the specified child key come next. If multiple children have a value of `false`, they are sorted lexicographically by key.
> 3. Children with a value of true for the specified child key come next. If multiple children have a value of `true`, they are sorted lexicographically by key.
> 4. Children with a numeric value come next, sorted in ascending order. If multiple children have the same numerical value for the specified > child node, they are sorted by key.
> 5. Strings come after numbers, and are sorted lexicographically in ascending order. If multiple children have the same value for the specified child node, they are ordered lexicographically by key.
> 6. Objects come last, and sorted lexicographically by key in ascending order.

To have the children ordered numerically, you would have to store `avgDrinkPrice` as a number. And `lati`, `longti` and `rating` are probably better stored as numbers, too.

The orderings that use your `lati`, `longti` and `rating` properties might appear to be numerical, but that would be because the string values being ordered probably have the same number of digits - which is not the case with `avgDrinkPrice`.