# Querying by range in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a range slider for prices of food , and based on the min and max of the slider , I want to display the foods which are in this range.

Slider code

```
multiSlider.setOnThumbValueChangeListener(new MultiSlider.SimpleChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onValueChanged(MultiSlider multiSlider, MultiSlider.Thumb thumb, int thumbIndex, int value) {
        if (thumbIndex == 0) {
            min = String.valueOf(value);
            min1.setText(min);
        } else {
            max = String.valueOf(value);
            max1.setText(max);
        }
    }
});

alertD.setPositiveButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        SearchPrice(min, max);
    }
});
```

Query Code

```
private void SearchPrice(String min, String max) {
    Query searchByName = foodList.orderByChild("price").startAt(min).endAt(max);
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Food> foodOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Food>().setQuery(searchByName, Food.class).build();

    Searchadapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(foodOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FoodViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Food model) {
            viewHolder.food_name.setText(model.getName());
            viewHolder.food_price.setText(model.getPrice());
```

Structure

[image]

I tried using the startAt and endAt , but its displaying food with prices outside of the range.Any help on this please ? Is there another way of doing this type of query?

Comment: Adding the firebase database structure might help us to be able to help you maybe?

Comment: You should also simplify the query code you posted. Try to pick out only the code concerned with firebase readtime database query

Comment: Please have a look , i added the structure.

Comment: @StefanoTokyo What it returns now? What's in the min - max value? would you add the whole query and the values of min -max too? However, I think you missed: `orderByKey()` before startAt and ...

Comment: My first guess is that you have `min` and `max` as numbers, while you the value of `price` in your database is a string. If that's the cause, try `foodList.orderByChild("price").startAt(""+min).endAt(""+max)`

Comment: How about this? `orderByKey().startAt("1").endAt("0");`

Comment: orderByKey() doesnt return anything. Lets say my min is "1" and my max is "10".It will return a food with the price of "10".But I have foods with price of "2" and "3".Why they aren't displaying too ?

Comment: Because you're storing numbers as strings, and strings are sorted lexicographically. In lexicographical order of you have number from 1 to 12, they are sorted as `"1", "10", "11", "12", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"`. So the range from `"1"` to `"10"` is precisely those two "numbers".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing numeric values as strings in the database. Firebase sorts strings lexicographically. In lexicographical order of you have number from 1 to 12, they are sorted as `"1", "10", "11", "12", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"`. So the range from `"1"` to `"10"` is precisely those two "numbers".

To solve this problem, store your numeric values as actual numbers in the database.

Also see:

- [firebase orderByChild returns weird order for only one child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905834/firebase-orderbychild-returns-weird-order-for-only-one-child/41905846#41905846)
- [Firebase query by date string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216858/firebase-query-by-date-string/38226376#38226376)
- [firebase database order by value working wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759707/firebase-database-order-by-value-working-wrong/44762297#44762297)
- [Firebase query ordering not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174300/firebase-query-ordering-not-working-properly/37192471#37192471)
- other [questions mentioning lexicographical sorting on Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+lexicographical+number)