# Swift Firebase Query

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using a Firebase query to return orders within a date range. The date is saved as a string. However, this is returning incorrect information.

```
    let startDate = "\(selectedDateStart.startOfMonth())"
    let endDate = "\(selectedDateEnd.endOfMonth())"
    let query = DATABASE.mainOrder.child(orderLocation).queryOrdered(byChild: "orderDate").queryStarting(atValue: startDate).queryEnding(atValue: endDate+"\u{f8ff}")
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:{ (snapshot) in
        if let tallies = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Any]] {
            self.allFilteredOrdersMonth = self.allFilteredOrdersMonth.merging(tallies) { (_, new) in new }
            for items in tallies.keys {
                print("Month Start Date Search: \(startDate), End Date Search: \(endDate), Order #: \(items), Order # Date Created: \(tallies[items]!["orderDate"]!)")
            }
        }
        completionHandler()
    })
```

I have attached one of the results below from a query.

startDate = 01/01/2022

endDate = 01/31/2022

Returned Order #: *****

Returned Order # Date Created: 01/19/2021

Comment: If you save the date as a string it will be sorted and compared as a string and not a date and furthermore with that particular format it will never work. You could get away with using a string if you used a format like yyyy-MM-dd, i.e 2022-01-01 because then 2021 would be sorted before 2022. Now 01/19 is sorted between 01/01 and 01/31

Comment: The issue is Firebase does not allow storing date

Comment: Read my whole comment

Comment: In lexicographical/alphabetical order (which is how strings are sorted) the value "01/01/2022" comes before "01/19/2021", because "01/01" comes before "01/19". The solution is (as Joakim and Alex have said) to store the data in either a string format that allows ordering, or as a timestamp number. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52728669/querying-by-range-in-firebase/52732340#52732340, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38226376/209103 and more from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D+lexicographical+number

Answer (score 1):

If you store dates as strings in the following format:

```
01/01/2022
```

And you try to perform an order, please note that strings are ordered [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order)

If you want to get the correct order, you should store the dates as timestamps.

According to your comment:

> The issue is Firebase does not allow storing date

It actually does:

```
let timestamps = ["startDate": ServerValue.timestamp(), "endDate": ServerValue.timestamp()] as [String : Any]
ref.updateChildValues(timestamps) { (err, ref) in
    if let err = err {
        print("failed to upload user data", err)
        return
    }

}
```

Comment: So I can just do this? db.child("orderDate").setValue(ServerValue.timestamp())

Comment: You should use a data structure that allows you to perform the update. Have you tried the solution in my answer? Does it work?